# Why Django won't render the sum that implied in pandas?

Tags: django, pandas, django-views

I'm manipulating a `Dataframe` using `pandas` and then I'm rendering the manipulated data to the user. I don't know if that's a `pandas` or a `Django` problem (or mine?). I tried exporting my `Dataframe` into `.csv` and re-reading it with pandas nothing.

Consider this `Dataframe`.

```
   A         B         C
0  foo      bar        10
1  foo      bar2       20
2  foo      bar        10
3  foo      bar2       250
```

```py
In my views.py,
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum().sum(level=['A', 
                                             'B']).fillna(0).reset_index()

context.update({'df': df.values})
return context
```

```html
In my template
{% for A, B, C in df %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ A }}</td>
    <td>{{ B }}</td>
    <td>{{ C }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm expecting to see

```
   A         B         C
0  foo      bar        20
1  foo      bar2       270
```

And I'm seeing

```
   A         B         C
0  foo      bar        1010
1  foo      bar2       20250
```

It's weird because I tried to export the `.csv` and reimport it. I believe it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I understand that, when you are trying to set a queryset in Django as a Dataframe, it still sees every single value as an object. So when you try to `sum`, `subtract`, etc, you will get the same problem I had.

How I dealt with it.

```
#TODO: Use Django to export the .csv file instead of pandas.
qs = list(MyModel.objects.value_list('A', 'B', 'C'))
df = pd.DataFrame(qs, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.to_csv('location_of_csv/temp.csv', sep=';', index=None)

df = pd.read_csv('location_of_csv/temp.csv', sep=';')
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum().sum(level=['A', 'B']).fillna(0).reset_index()

context.update({'df': df.values})
```